# How does a node module resolve a file path?

Tags: reactjs, npm

An imported module contains a .png file that I would like to overwrite with another one. On the web application I can see that the reference to this file isn't change even though it is not just a module of another project.

My question is: How to file paths work in a node module that is being imported? The built project should have another structure, right?

Answer (score 1):

The `import` statement always takes the relative path from the file or searches the module in node_modules.

If you are writing something like 
`import Abc from './abc.js'`
it will search for abc.js in the same directory. If you want to go to the parent directory, you can use `../` instead of `./`. Whatever the location of the file you give, will be calculated from the current file. This current file can be imported again and the next file  cares about only this file and not what it imports

If you are not using `./` or `../` then nodejs will look for the module in node_modules folder.

`import React from 'react'`